# C# - How to allow multiple filetypes in an OpenFileDialog?

Tags: c#, winforms, filter, file-extension

I knew this once but I keep forgetting; How do I allow multiple filetypes in one filter entry of the OpenFileDialog?

```
Text files|*.txt          // this is OK.

Text files|*.txt,*.text   // how do I get this??
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Semicolon:

```
files|*.txt;*.text
```

Comment: How can i have .pdf,.xls,.doc ..what would be the filter for that?

Comment: @Sangram I'm pretty sure you just typed out your own answer for the most part

Comment: @Sinaesthetic: LOL. Old comment. Yes, i really did answer it.